# cannot load such file -- sqlite3/database (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to setup basic installation and initiation of server using Rails 7.0.4 on Ruby 3.1.0, i have settings sqliet3 3.49.4 . I use windows.   I'm facing the following error message.

[image]

How can I avoid this error message.

Comment: Do you have Sqlite (the app not the gem) installed on your server? Try `Sqlite3 --version`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

Try

> gem uninstall sqlite3

and

> gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby